# Accessing instance variables inside a class in Python 3

Tags: python, instance-variables, class-variables

I'm having some issues with Python as an OO language. I learned OO with Java and Python, while similar, seems to have some key differences. I'm trying to write a basic chatbot (I mean really basic) and for some reason I'm unable to access variables from inside the class. Here is my code:

chatbot.py

```
import random


class Chatbot:

    greetings = ["Hello", "WAZZZZZUUUPPPPP", "Howdy"]
    salutations = ["Bye", "Bye Felicia", "Adios", "Fine, I didn't want to talk to you anymore anyway"]
    how_are_you = ["I'm good", "I've been better", "Better than you"]
    whats_up = ["Not much", "Thinking about life, the universe, and everything", "Just wondering why you're communicating with a human in a box"]

    def respond(self,text):
        myText = text.lower();
        print(text)
        if text == "hello":
            print(self.greetings[random.randint(0, greetings.length - 1)])
```

and here's the calling code, rowdy-messenger.py:

```
from chatbot import Chatbot

print("Welcome to rowdy messenger")
hello = Chatbot()
hello.respond("hello")
```

The error text I'm getting is (I omitted the absolute path)

```
...
   File "rowdy-messenger.py", line 5, in <module>
    hello.respond("hello")
  line 15, in respond
    print(greetings[random.randint(0, greetings.length - 1)])
NameError: name 'greetings' is not defined
```

My questions:

1) Why am I getting this error? I'm used to Java where this would be just fine (using this instead of self of course)

2) Is it better to use these as class variables or instance variables? In the calling code it will only be instantiated once anyway but I figured for "large" data it's better to only instantiate constants once.

Comment: Why one time you correctly referred to `self.greetings` and second time made a mistake with just `greetings`?

Comment: "Is it better to use these as class variables or instance variables?": since you're not changing them, you could leave them as class variables. But creating instance variables doesn't eat a lot of mem; only references.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Wow, I didn't even realize that, thank you!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre So, it's not like Java? It only creates one space in memory and then sets different pointers?

Comment: yes, exactly the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't use `self` consistently. That line refers to `greetings` *twice*; the first time you do use `self`, but the second time you don't.

Python's "explicit is better than implicit" philosophy means you always need to use `self`.

Note, though, the code could be simplified to `print(random.choice(self.greetings))`.

Comment: I didn't even notice the second "greetings" was missing the self, thank you!
Also, I didn't know about the choice method, I guess I need to read the docs a bit more thoroughly >.<

Answer (score 1):

https://syntaxdb.com/ref/python/class-variables

If you're intending for greeting to be an instance variable (it looks like you are), you'll want to also prefix `self` to the greeting declaration.

This is one of the many differences between python's take on OOP and that of Java (no `this` necessary in the greeting declaration)